# Trying to run old NetLogo with old Java(6) under jenv gets noop error

Tags: java, netlogo, macos-catalina, jenv

I'm trying to run an old version of NetLogo (5.0.2) on OS X (Catalina) which requires Java6. I'm using jenv (installed under brew cask management). It seems to find the right java, but I'm getting the below error:

```
com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.java.usage.BundledApp
com.apple.message.domain.version: 1.6.0_65-b14-468
com.apple.message.signature: org.nlogo.NetLogo / org.nlogo.app.App
com.apple.message.signature2: org.nlogo.app.App
com.apple.message.signature3: BundledApp
com.apple.message.result: noop
```

Comment: Fwiw, NetLogo 6 can import NetLogo 5 models.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've run NetLogo 5.3.1 on Catalina.  It comes with a bundled Java so might have a better chance of working out of the box.  Are you able to try that for your purposes?  http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.3.1/